# Errors when applying the layout to an android app in Android Studio. Coded with Processing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, autolayout, processing

This the screenshot of the error message when I try running the app on my android device
[image]
Can somebody assist me in solving these errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.978 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: i tried every possible solution i know, but the error remains same!!!  if you have any possible solution then please tell..

Comment: Can you share your gradle files?